QuickFixj - Message does not contain any field separator
This is the quickfixj message I pass and I see that it gives "message does not contain any field separator error". I pass it using kafka and use json to parse to this message content using string utf-8  encoding below :  "8=FIX.4.4\u00019=100\u000135=M\u000134=68388\u000149=BBSL\u000152=20240508-19:05:55.933\u000156=BBC\u00011=GGG\u00016=23.71\u000115=USD\u000122=5\u000148=33738D879\u000153=76\u000178=1"
When I try to print content, it shows the above but when we try to parse it using the data dictionary, it gives message does not contain field separator error.
But When I pass the same by hardcoding as string in code, it shows me this message without \u0001 and goes through fine with parsing using quickfixj.
"8=FIX.4.4 9=100 35=M 34=68388 49=BBSL 152=20240508-19:05:55.933 56=BBC 1=GGG 6=23.71 15=USD 22=5 48=33738D879 53=76 78=1"
trying to understand what encoding or something else going wrong when it is parsed using json and then converted to string to pass to quickfixj .

Please show the code where you "use json to parse to this message content using string utf-8 encoding"

JsonMapper jsonMapper = new JsonMapper();
JsonNode node = jsonMapper.readTree(message.value());
String message = node.get("key").get("data").toString().trim();
messageEncoded=StringUtils.newStringUtf8(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(message).array());

In order to send a FIX message on its own or as part of a json message you need to escape the string as it contains special characters that some messaging systems don't support, like the /u0001 character, and they either strip it out or fail to send the message. When sending the message on a topic try escaping it like this:
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(message.toString())

And on the other side unescape it:
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(message.toString())

I use StringEscapeUtils from apache commons-text
